# implement youtube API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, youtube-api

Currently, I am developing an App in which I have implemented you tube API for sending videos

into you tube.For this I have used https://github.com/nparry/gdata-objectivec-clien/tree/master/Source

library and its work fine for me when I am individually use it.but when I am merge this API

in my working App it shows me following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataYouTubeMediaGroup", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataUtilities", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaTitle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleYouTube", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaKeywords", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeViewController.o
  "_kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory", referenced from:
      -[YoutubeViewController uploadPressed:] in YoutubeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryYouTubeUpload", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaCategory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have searched so hard for removing this error but can't find any solution.How can I solve 
this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't linked the gdata files to the target. Easiest way to do that is remove them from the project, and then add them again, making sure you check the box next to your project under "add to targets".
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

this is an error that comes on adding files from external sources into project, all you need to do is : go to "Build Phases" under "Targets", there you need to add all .m files in "Compile Sources".